# PFA for cardinal preserving forcing notions and the CH

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, continuum-hypothesis

Let **$FA_{\aleph_1}$(cardinal preserving proper forcings)** be the forcing axiom: if $\mathbb{P}$ is a  cardinal preserving proper forcing notion and $(D_\xi)_{\xi<\omega_1}$ are dense subsets of $\mathbb{P},$
then there exists a filter $G \subseteq \mathbb{P}$ which meets all $D_\xi$'s, $\xi < \omega_1$.

Does this forcing axiom decide CH. More precisely,

> **Question.** Assuming the existence of large cardinals, is **$FA_{\aleph_1}$(cardinal preserving proper forcings)** consistent with large values of the continuum?

Comment: If mean, it implies MA (because every ccc forcing is proper and cardinal preserving), so presumably it decides $\lnot\sf CH$. Since it follows from $\sf PFA$, it's compatible with $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$. So by "large" do you mean larger than $\aleph_2$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Yes, sure, i mean given any $\kappa,$ can we get it with the continuum above $\kappa$?. Th motivation comes from the fact that to show PFA decides CH, we use forcings which collapse the continuum!.

Comment: Are you married to the idea that we can only intersect $\aleph_1$ dense open sets? Normally to get a large continuum (as a consequence) we need to intersect more.

Comment: Also, note that this class of forcings has a terrible iteration properties.

Comment: By "decide CH", do you mean just whether CH is true or false?  Because hitting $\aleph_1$ dense subsets of Cohen forcing implies that CH is false, right?   But deciding the value of the continuum is another matter.

Comment: I mean determine its value, like what PFA does, namely it implies the continuum is $\aleph_2$.

Comment: If it determines the value, it has to be $\aleph_2$. So I guess your question can be clarified by asking specifically if this forcing axiom is consistent with a larger continuum. This is a question I'd ask David Aspero, not MathOverflow, to be honest. I'll alert him to this.

Comment: This is related to Rahman Muhammadpour's question on whether forcing axioms for proper posets of cardinality $\aleph_1$ imply the continuum is $\aleph_2$, See:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350880/how-bad-a-proper-forcing-of-size-aleph-1-can-be